# watson speech to text issue in node.js

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have created a  watson chatbot with conversation, STT and TTS services from below node.js code,

https://github.com/mirkorodriguez/ibm-watson-conversation-full

I have used my English language conversation, STT and TTS services , I am able to get the proper responses back from conversation but when i click on microphone and speak in English, the application is taking the input as Spanish language and responding back with Spanish. Please let me know what needs to be changed to get english language instead of spanish [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmX9U.png)input.below is the screenshot for the same.

Comment: hi All, any idea about what is causing the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

That will be because the sample that you are using will have hard-coded the language to be Spanish. It looks like the sample you are pointing at is actually a clone of the Standard Car Dashboard demo, which is in English, so all you need to do is go to the original sample.

If you do want to change the language, then how to is encapsulated in the forum entry here - https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/447834/change-the-text-to-speech-voice-to-frensh-in-the-c.html?childToView=447992#answer-447992

Comment: thanks for the reply @chughts , i have fixed the issue.